Keyboard toolbar in swift UI unexpected behaviour
I have been working on a workout logging app.
I have 3 tabs inside a tab view. Every tab is using a Navigation stack and navigation title of their own. 2 out of 3 tabs have toolbar on the keybaord. Whenever I try to launch the app on my phone they don't show up. Sometimes they do and sometimes they don't.
But as soon as I put the tabview inside a Navigation Stack the toolbar seems to work everytime but now my navigation titles on 3 different tabs are gone like they don't even exist. I can put a common title for all the tabs by putting the navigation title to tab view but not the individual tabs.
I'm very new to swiftUI please help me understand what's going on.
Also I get some weird warnings whenever my keyboard becomes active. Is that a normal behaviour?
Tab View
import SwiftUI

struct Tabs: View {
    var body: some View {
            TabView {
                // Tab for viewing the workout history
                SettingsTab()
                    .tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear") }
                // Tab for viewing the workout history
                SettingsTab()
                    .tabItem { Label("Settings", systemImage: "gear") }
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Tabs()
        .modelContainer(for: [Workout.self], inMemory: true)
}

Settings Tab
import SwiftUI

struct SettingsTab: View {
    @AppStorage("isWeightInKG") private var isWeightInKG = true
    @AppStorage("incrementWeight") private var incrementWeight = 2.5

    @State private var incrementWeightState: Double?
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            List{
                Section("Weight settings"){
                    // Weight units
                    HStack(spacing: 32) {
                        Text("Weight Units")
                        Picker("", selection: $isWeightInKG, content: {
                            Text("KG").tag(true)
                            Text("LB").tag(false)
                        })
                        .pickerStyle(.segmented)
                        
                    }
                    // Increment weight
                    HStack{
                        Text("Increment weight")
                        Spacer()
                        TextField(
                            String(incrementWeight * (isWeightInKG ? 1: 2.2)),
                            value: $incrementWeightState,
                            format: .number
                        )
                        .focused($isFocused)
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .font(.title3)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .onChange(of: incrementWeightState, {
                            if incrementWeightState != nil {
                                let m = isWeightInKG ? 1: 2.2
                                incrementWeight = incrementWeightState! / m
                            }
                        })
                        .onChange(of: isWeightInKG, {
                            if incrementWeightState != nil {
                                let m = isWeightInKG ? 1: 2.2
                                incrementWeightState = incrementWeight * m
                            }
                        })
                        .toolbar {
                            if isFocused {
                                ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                                    Button("Done", systemImage: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down"){
                                        isFocused = false
                                        incrementWeightState = nil
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Text(isWeightInKG ? "KG" : "LB")
                            .font(.caption)
                    }
                }
                
                // Delete Entire data present in the app
            }
            .navigationTitle("App Settings")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SettingsTab()
}


Please show a [mcve].

I added the example code that is causing the misbehavior in the app

Only put a NavigationStack in a TabView, not the other way around.

I have 3 tabs inside a tab view, no you don't, you have two and there are
both the same. Whenever I try to launch the app on my phone they don't show up.
show the code where you declare your App and call Tabs. Seems you are also using SwiftData,
is that correct?

This is just an example which is creating the same issue. In my app i'm also using swift data but the code that I shared are causing the problem without even having the swift data. Even if the tabs are same why are they causing this issue?
